# Adding button and other things to panel, not in console

Tags: google-earth-engine, user-interface, panel

I am new to GEE and now I am learning on my first GEE Apps.
I have watched some tutorial about making some button in my apps. But, all button I made goes to console which I can't use or click when I try my apps. Can we add those buttons to the panel? I mean under the panel's title. So I can make some navigation to people visiting my apps.

Here is my code. What is the problem?

```
// Membuat Administrasi Indonesia
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level1");
var indonesia = countries.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_CODE',116));
Map.setCenter(117.91510287926177,-1.7928833046634025, 5);
// Map.addLayer(indonesia);

// 1. Hansen Tree Loss Over 2000 - 2021
var hansen = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2021_v1_9');
var treeLossVisParam = {
  bands: ['lossyear'],
  min:0,
  max:21,
  palette: ['yellow','red']
};
// Map.addLayer(hansen.clip(indonesia), treeLossVisParam, 'Tree Loss Year 2000 - 2021');

// Membuat panel widget
var mainPanel = ui.Panel({
  style: {width: '350px'}
});

// Memberikan judul widget
var title = ui.Label({
  value: 'Forest Monitoring Indonesia',
  style: {'fontSize': '25px'}
});
var subtitle1 = ui.Label({
  value: 'Select Environmental Analysis :',
  style: {'fontSize': '20px', 'textAlign':'center'}
});

//Menambahkan judul pada panel
mainPanel.add(title)
mainPanel.add(subtitle1)

// Menampilkan Panel Utama
ui.root.add(mainPanel)

//Nama dari checkbox
var checkbox = ui.Checkbox ('Tree Loss Year 2000 - 2021', false);
var checkbox2 = ui.Checkbox ('Tree Coverage %', false);
var checkbox3 = ui.Checkbox ('Forest Canopy Height 2005', false);

checkbox.onChange(function(checked){
  // Menampilkan Layer ke-1
  Map.layers().get(1).setShown(checked);
})

//print fungsi checkbox
// print(checkbox);

print(checkbox);
//Membuat fungsi transparansi dengan slider
var slider1 = ui.Slider();
slider1.setValue(0.6); // Set a default value.
slider1.onChange(function(value) {
Map.layers().get(1).setOpacity(value);
});
print(slider1);



//membuat label pada button
var buttonPekanbaruRiau = ui.Button({
label: 'Pekanbaru, Riau',
onClick: function() {
Map.setCenter(101.460425,  0.472669,8);
}
});
print(buttonPekanbaruRiau);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `print` statements for widgets and add the following lines at the bottom.

```
mainPanel.add(checkbox);
mainPanel.add(checkbox2);
mainPanel.add(checkbox3);
mainPanel.add(slider1);
mainPanel.add(buttonPekanbaruRiau);
```

[image]